# how to get GET /v2/quota_definitions api using c-python-client module

Tags: python, cloud-foundry, cf-python-client

I am using `cf-python-client` module downloaded from this [link](https://github.com/cloudfoundry-community/cf-python-client) and I am trying to get all the org quotas present in the cf target api.

I am able to get the organisation information by this
client.v2.organizations.get(org_guid) but now I want to get the org quotas and the API required is `GET /v2/quota_definitions` but i dont know how to use it through `cf-python-client` module.

This is how i am connecting to Cloudfoundry

```
from cloudfoundry_client.client import CloudFoundryClient
client = CloudFoundryClient(target_endpoint, proxy=proxy, verify=False)
client.init_with_user_credentials( 'admin', 'password' )
```

Comment: iam guessing this cant be done!

Comment: were you able to get the quota definitions?